# Sql client transactions from code vs database-controlled transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, transactions, isolation-level

I've always done transactions from within stored procedures but now I need to wrap a bunch of "dynamic" statements executed from code against `sp_executesql` in a transaction.

Specifically I need the `READ UNCOMMITED` isolation level for these in some cases (I know what that does, and yes, that's what I need). This is SQL2008.

My question is this: If I use the `BeginTransaction()` method of my SqlConnection instance with the isolation level set to `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` will that have the same effect as if I executed a stored proc that has the `READ UNCOMMITED` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will.

The SqlConnection uses the SQL native client, and a call to `BeginTransaction` causes exactly this to be sent to the server:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL <WHATEVER>; BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```